# ffmpeg error: cur_dts is invalid

Tags: linux, audio, video, ffmpeg

I'm trying to record video and audio from my webcam with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -s uhd2160 -i /dev/video0 -f pulse -channels 1 -i default video.mpg
```

but it seems to get stuck in some endless loop at the bottom of the output that looks like this:

```
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
cur_dts is invalid (this is harmless if it occurs once at the start per stream)
...
```

Full output with `-report` flag enabled: https://pastebin.com/bV1ePJ2u

I can record video and audio separately just fine:

```
ffmpeg -f v4l2 -input_format mjpeg -s uhd2160 -i /dev/video0 video.mpg
ffmpeg -f pulse -channels 1 -i default audio.wav
```

So what could be the problem here? I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 kernel 4.14.1

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Are you able to record video and audio in parallel by running individual ffmpeg commands in parallel.Perhaps you can merge both streams after that. Also I may be wrong, but I think this issue started showing up after ffmpeg4.2. Maybe try using another version or building ffmpeg from source. Also I found this: https://superuser.com/questions/1622300/ffmpeg-transcoding-failing-on-cur-dts-is-invalid. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can combine them into one file by using this command (in cmd for Windows OS)

```
        C:/this is just path of ffmpeg lib/ffmpeg_shared/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg -i "video_part.ts" -i "audio_part.aac" -map 0:V:0 -map 1:a:0 -c copy -f mp4 -movflags +faststart "./new/combined_file_name.mp4"
```